# SQL/PHP - Join 2 Tables with data from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the query for SQL statement

```
UPDATE TrendingEvents
    SET Name = ?, Image = ?, Date = ?, EventCategory = ?
    WHERE ID = ?;')
```

I would like to access the ID of the other table within my TrendingEvents table. This is the example I've done although it doesn't fully work;

```
UPDATE TrendingEvents INNER JOIN
       Events AS eID
       ON TrendingEvents.ID = Events.ID
 SET Name = ?, Image = ?, Date = ?, EventCategory = ?
 WHERE eID = ?;')
```

I would like to update the TrendingEvents table with the ID column from Events table.

The error I'm getting from my statement is

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'Name'
```

Which just shows that I've poorly designed my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misused the table alias, so your query should not even compile.  Try this:

```
UPDATE TrendingEvents te INNER JOIN
       Events e
       ON te.ID = e.ID
 SET te.Name = ?,
     te.Image = ?,
     te.Date = ?,
     te.EventCategory = ?
 WHERE e.eID = ?;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both tables seem to contain a column called Name. You need to properly prefix the fields with the table name, like :

```
UPDATE 
    TrendingEvents AS t
    INNER JOIN Events AS e
        ON t.ID = e.ID 
    SET 
        t.Name = ?, 
        t.Image = ?, 
        t.Date = ?, 
        t.EventCategory = ? 
    WHERE e.eID = ?
```